# How to make a dictionary including list in a faster way

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary in which each key has a list (eg. {A:[f,g,d], B:[g,k,s,r]}).
My current code uses for loop.
However, many people say that it is better to avoid for loop in python.
So I would like to know another way to do the same thing in a faster way (maybe without using for loop).
Thank you.

```py
def Dictionary(data):
    Dictionary={}
    for i in data:
        Dictionary.setdefault((i[0], i[1]), []).append(i[2])
    return Dictionary
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python list comprehension" and "dict comprehension", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: A loop can be ok when populating a dict.  Take a look at `collections.defaultdict` as well.

Comment: _many people say_ is not a good enough point to motivate optimization IMHO. I don't know if is faster but you can use defaultdict as pylang pointed out

Comment: You really want a tuple as key?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary comprehension. Also, for loops can be very useful and efficient. It is about using the correct tool for the job. The documentation on both dict comprehensions and for loops are a very good place to start